# How to set min and max value in jquery slider?

Tags: jquery, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using jquery - Filamentgroup slider. I want to limit the slider movement.

**Javascript**

```
$('select#valueA, select#valueB').selectToUISlider({
            sliderOptions: {
                    change:function(e, ui) {
                        return false;

                    }
            },
            labels: 12
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
        <label for="valueA">From:</label>
        <select name="valueA" id="valueA">
            <option value="6am">6:00</option>
            <option value="7am">7:00</option>
            <option value="8am">8:00</option>
            <option value="9am" selected="selected">9:00</option>
            <option value="10am">10:00</option>
            <option value="11am">11:00</option>
            <option value="Noon">Noon</option>
            <option value="1pm">1:00</option>
            <option value="2pm">2:00</option>
            <option value="3pm">3:00</option>
            <option value="4pm">4:00</option>
            <option value="5pm">5:00</option>
            <option value="6pm">6:00</option>
            <option value="7pm">7:00</option>
            <option value="8pm">8:00</option>
            <option value="9pm">9:00</option>
            <option value="10pm">10:00</option>
            <option value="11pm">11:00</option>
            <option value="12pm">12:00</option>
        </select>

        <label for="valueB">To:</label>
        <select name="valueB" id="valueB">
            <option value="6am">6:00</option>
            <option value="7am">7:00</option>
            <option value="8am">8:00</option>
            <option value="9am">9:00</option>
            <option value="10am">10:00</option>
            <option value="11am">11:00</option>
            <option value="Noon">Noon</option>
            <option value="1pm">1:00</option>
            <option value="2pm">2:00</option>
            <option value="3pm">3:00</option>
            <option value="4pm">4:00</option>
            <option value="5pm">5:00</option>
            <option value="6pm">6:00</option>
            <option value="7pm">7:00</option>
            <option value="8pm">8:00</option>
            <option value="9pm" selected="selected">9:00</option>
            <option value="10pm">10:00</option>
            <option value="11pm">11:00</option>
            <option value="12pm">12:00</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

How can i control slider movement. That means if anyone move the slider some position, i need to pragmatically move the slider to particular position.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the plugin doesn't allow to override the min and max value via an select element you should use a input element

```
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="1"  />
```

and then

```
$('#slider').selectToUISlider();
```

Comment: this code doesn't worked for me.I have edited my question. Please check that and advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite positive what you're trying to achieve, but taking a look at the code samples from the jQuery-UI website for the [slider control](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin).

Here's an example from the docs:

#### Javascript

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 37,
    min: 20,  //valueA
    max: 50,  //valueB
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

#### HTML

```html
<label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" />
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

#### Working demo in Stack Snippets & [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/EHLQL/)

```js
$(function () {
  $("#slider-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 37,
    min: 30,
    max: 50,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range-min").slider("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" />
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

Comment: this code doesn't worked for me.I have edited my question. Please check that and advice me.